# SQL Subqueries, map one field to another, and make a separate lookup/count against another table

Tags: sql, count, subquery

[image]

I have a spreadsheet with about ~1000 rows, and 2 columns.
I've been given Postgres DB access and have been tasked with making some lookups. I think manually this would take forever, I am hopeful that there is a way easier way to do this w/ SQL queries

1. I need to get an associated `UserID` from each row, by making a lookup in the `users` table, which has a `PhoneNumber` column
2. There is another table `user_orders` where `UserId` maps to an `Order`. I need to count how many `Orders` each user has made

So what I'm looking for is to convert Phone Numbers -> UserID -> Order Count.

I am using Postico to construct queries against my database. I can figure out a way to export the phone numbers into a comma separated list, but I'm completely lost from that step

Comment: Export your spreadsheet to CSV format .. Write a script (in your favorite language) OR use a program to import into your database .. Then you can write all the queries you want :).  --  This would make it super easy for `JOINS` and whatnot in case you needed to write more complicated queries in the future ..

Comment: unfortunately i don't have the bandwidth to setup a script, i was trying to see if this was possible strictly through SQL queries. What I'm starting with is just getting a comma-separated list of userIDs. Hopefully I can figure out counting orders from there